# Python: Groupby First Non NaN Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id    number   
1      13
1      13
1      NaN
1      NaN
2      11
2      11
2      11
2      NaN
```

I want to find the first non-NaN value per id and mark it with a 1. The result should look like this:

```
id    number     code   
1      13         NaN
1      13         1
1      NaN        NaN
1      NaN        NaN
2      11         NaN
2      11         NaN
2      11         1
2      NaN        NaN
```

I tried the following command and then go from there:

```
df["test"] = df.groupby("id")["number"].first_valid_index()
```

It gives me the following error: Cannot access callable attribute 'first_valid_index' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Then I tried this:

```
df['test'] = df.groupby("id")['number'].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())
```

But this gives me just a column of Nats...

Does anybody know how the problem could be solved efficiently?

Comment: That looks like the last valid index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean `last_valid_index`, you can `apply` the `last_valid_index` function and `loc` to assign -

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id').number.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index), 'code'] = 1
df

   id  number  code
0   1    13.0   NaN
1   1    13.0   1.0
2   1     NaN   NaN
3   1     NaN   NaN
4   2    11.0   NaN
5   2    11.0   NaN
6   2    11.0   1.0
7   2     NaN   NaN
```

---

Alternatively, using `groupby` + `idxmax` -

```
df.loc[df.number.notnull().cumsum().groupby(df.id).idxmax(), 'code'] = 1
df

   id  number  code
0   1    13.0   NaN
1   1    13.0   1.0
2   1     NaN   NaN
3   1     NaN   NaN
4   2    11.0   NaN
5   2    11.0   NaN
6   2    11.0   1.0
7   2     NaN   NaN
```

Comment: What if one group is entirely `NaN`?

Comment: @BallpointBen I suppose it would spuriously assign a 1 to the last row in the group.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this...

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x : x['number'].dropna()).reset_index(level=1)['level_1'].max(level=0),'code']=1
df
Out[628]: 
   id  number  code
0   1    13.0   NaN
1   1    13.0   1.0
2   1     NaN   NaN
3   1     NaN   NaN
4   2    11.0   NaN
5   2    11.0   NaN
6   2    11.0   1.0
7   2     NaN   NaN
```

Comment: @piRSquared yep, fix it :-)